# Printing a file to console received with a POST request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm receiving a json encoded file using nodejs and busboy. Now I want to read this file and print it on the console.

I guess this should be easy, but somehow I don't get how to read and print the whole file..

```
router.addRoute('/', function (req, res, params) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

        busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);

            // We are streaming! Handle chunks
            file.on('data', function (data) {
        //read file
            });

            // Completed streaming the file.
            file.on('end', function () {
                console.log('Finished with ' + fieldname);
            });
        });

        // Listen for event when Busboy is finished parsing the form.
        busboy.on('finish', function () {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end();
        });

        req.pipe(busboy);
    }
});
```

Comment: This code looks fine. What doesn’t work about it? (Did you mean to `console.log(data);`? Do you want to concatenate the chunks?)

Comment: Seems like my question was not clear. I'm receiving the file, so far so good. but now I want to print the content of the file in clear text. the data in the callback just gives <Buffer 5b 7b...

Comment: `file.pipe(process.stdout);`? You can also decode your buffer objects into whichever format you need, e.g. `console.log(data.toString('utf8'));`

Comment: and if I want to have the content into a variable?

Comment: Push the chunk from each `data` event into an array and call `Buffer.concat` on that in `end`.

Comment: lol, it is too easy. sorry, I must have a very bad day :D thx

Answer (score 0):

in "file.on('data')" callback you can get the content of file as string.

```
    router.addRoute('/', function (req, res, params) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

        busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);

            // We are streaming! Handle chunks
            file.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            });

            // Completed streaming the file.
            file.on('end', function () {
                console.log('Finished with ' + fieldname);
            });
        });

        // Listen for event when Busboy is finished parsing the form.
        busboy.on('finish', function () {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end();
        });

        req.pipe(busboy);
    }
});
```

if it come as incomplete streaming data . that file.on('data') will trigger each time with part of file content until the file got completed.In the case you need file.on('end') callback and a global variable . see below ,

```
router.addRoute('/', function (req, res, params) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var wholeData = '';
        var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

        busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);

            // We are streaming! Handle chunks
            file.on('data', function (data) {
            wholeData+=data;
            });

            // Completed streaming the file.
            file.on('end', function () {
                console.log('Finished with ' + fieldname);
                console.log(wholeData);
            });
        });

        // Listen for event when Busboy is finished parsing the form.
        busboy.on('finish', function () {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end();
        });

        req.pipe(busboy);
    }
});
```